# Detecting keypress in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have read many posts and answers, but they all seem to be out of date.

My goal is to be able to "tab" through text and run a function on enter and/or spacebar. I have tried `keyCode`, `charCode`, `key`, `which`, `keypress`, `keyup`, `keydown` etc...

I have a text node that I can tab through using:

```
.attr('role', 'button')
.attr('tabindex', '0')
.attr('focusable', 'true')
.on('click', sel)
.on('keypress', function(){if(key == 13 || key == 32){return sel}})
```

The on click is perfect and the tab works, just the function is not called when the space and enter are used.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `d3.event.keyCode`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#event), `d3.event`...:

> ... is set during the invocation of an event listener, and is reset after the listener terminates. Use this to access standard event fields.

Here is a basic demo. Click on "foo", "bar" or "baz" to focus, then press any key and look at the console:

```js
var body = d3.select("body");
var p = body.selectAll(null)
  .data(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .attr('tabindex', '0')
  .attr('focusable', 'true')
  .html(String)
  .on("keypress", function() {
    if(d3.event.keyCode === 32 || d3.event.keyCode === 13){
    console.log("Congrats, you pressed enter or space!")
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```